# Angularjs scope lost when creating highcharts click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have run into a scoping problem when creating click functions on the nodes of my graphs built using Angularjs, Highcharts and the highcharts-ng directive.

The problem I am having is that any angular directives or functionality I place in my click function does not work.

Here is a simplified version of my problem - http://jsfiddle.net/47m46/8/

Click on any graph node to see the click function being called. Clicking on the close button should fire an ng-click event which loads up a simple function that displays an alert

This is the html that my click function generates:

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <button ng-click="closeDrillDown()">Close</button>
    <h2>Positive Sentiment</h2>
    <p class="drillDownInfo"><strong>20%</strong> of posts where we can determine a sentiment are Positive</p>
</div>
```

This is the function called with ng-click which does not get triggered

```
$scope.closeDrillDown = function() {
      alert('function works');
    };
```

The author of the highcharts-ng directive mentioned in the following thread https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/56 that "These events (click function) will be outside of the angular world though so you'll need to wrap them with an apply or similar."

So my question is: How do I give my highcharts click function access to Angularjs? I have tried to use $scope.$apply() but my limited knowleadge of this facet of angular has not given me any results.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/47m46/10/

Comment: Wow thanks man! I think this has given me enough information to carry on from here.

Comment: Maybe instead of trigger ng-click, use jquery and run a function. http://jsfiddle.net/47m46/11/

Comment: Hi Sebastian this is not really an option for me as I would like to use Angular functionality inside of the click function

Comment: I introduce you only workaround ;)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, the solution to this question would be the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/47m46/10/

```
var content = '<div id = "postListPopUpContainer"><div id = "postListPopUp"><div><button ng-click="closeDrillDown()">Close</button><h2>' + this.category + ' ' + this.series.name + '</h2>' +
                                '<p class="drillDownInfo"><strong>' + this.y + '%</strong> of posts where we can determine a sentiment are ' + this.category + '</p></div></div></div>';

$('#myCtrl').append($compile(content)($scope));
```

The part to take note of would be where we use $compile(). This places the generated html into the Angularjs context.